# Netty 5, how to bind some specify info in channel

Tags: java, websocket, netty

ClientA and Client B connect to the NettyServer.

when the connection builds, there is a channel between Client and NettyServer, I want when channel active, I can add Client side info in the channel, so that I can store like Map(ClientInfo,Channel). The on the server side, I can use Map.get(ClientInfo) to get the specific channel, then I can use channel.writeAndFlush() to send message to the specific client.

how to implement it? Use attachment? But, in neety5 API ChannelHandler, the attachment example is not the way I want to use. I wander if I can add attachment at Client side, and I can get it at the Server side?

Comment: To answer your final question, no. Attachments are local. You don't state *why* 'the attachment example is not the way [you] want to use it.'

Comment: so I can not use attachment to pass some specify info from client to server?

Comment: That's what 'attachments are local' says. Attachments aren't magic. The channel itself is the connection. There isn't a mysterious side channel.

Comment: Ok， tahnks. maybe I will try other ways to solve it. send a specify message to server, then bind the message and the channel id in a map.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AttributeKey or AttributeMap to store your client info, and store them into channel or channelContext, if necessary you can use them using get or set method.

Comment: But not between the server and the client, which is what the question is about.